# Rewrite catalog_blocks_layer_view does nothing

Tags: module, configuration, blocks, overrides

I've tried rewriting catalog_blocks_layer_view with this config in a module (the module is turned on and works.) but my rewrite isn't rewriting and I'm not getting any errors. Does anyone know what could be up? Thank you!

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Mods>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Mods>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer_view>Company_Mods_Block_Catalog_Layer_View</layer_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

rewrite:

```
<?php
class Company_Mods_Block_Catalog_Layer_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View {
    public function getFilters()
    {
        $filters = array();

        $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
        foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
            $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
        }

        return $filters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `config.xml` looks correct.  That means one, or many, or all, of the following are true

1. You're missing the module's `app/etc/module/*` declaration file,
2. You have your block class in the incorrect location
3. Your block actually is rewritten, but you think it's not for an incorrect reason

Download [this working `Company_Mods` module](http://alanstorm.com/2013/projects/Company_Mods.tar)  and diff it vs. your module. If there are no differences, come back and tell us why you think your module is not working.

Comment: Or there is already another extension overwriting the block.

Comment: Hmmm, I must be expecting functionality that isn't making sense. I edited your module to have the code I've added above, and it's still having no affect. I'm attempting to remove the top "categories" from the filterable left nav. This is a clean install so there shouldn't be anything overwriting this block already.